# Calling an Objective-C function from JavaScript hosted on some web page

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

I have an IOS application which has a web browser in it.

When this web browser is displayed, it navigates to a page on Internet, say http://myexample.com/myiosapp.

Is it possible to place a javascript code on this web site, which, when downloaded to phone, communicates with the native application? Can it call an Objective-C method, or write something to storage space of this application?

Ex.
Code hosted on myexample.com/myios app:

```
function saveSomeString() {
    xcode.Save("somestring");
}
```

should call an Objective-C function named Save, which saves incoming string parameter to local storage.

Comment: You can use local storage in js it's really simple! See  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: But after using local storage, can I read that information by XCode?

Comment: No. I hadn't understood what you were looking for.

Comment: @SerhatÖzgel: XCode is a development environment, not a programming language. So it has no methods. You probably mean an Objective-C method. I've changed the title and the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is a bit hacky.

**On the Objective-C side:**

Basically, in the UIWebView, you will use method shouldStartLoadWithRequest (from the UIWebViewDelegate) which is called before a URL request starts:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

**On Javascript side:**

Your javascript code will navigate to a 'fake' URL that you will filter on the method above. Something like:

```
window.location = "js2objc://save:param";
```

**Back on the Objective-C side:**

Inside the method I mentioned earlier, you look for the keyword js2objc (or whichever you choose) and then extract the info and take any appropriate action:

```
if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"js2objc"]){
    // extract the parameters and save them, o do whatever action you need
    return NO;  // so the UIWebView doesn't actually follow the url
}
```

Comment: This should do the trick, thanks. I'll accept it once I try it.

Comment: I found a tutorial that describes the above step-by-step. http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/