# Evaluate Javascript in WebView iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I am displaying the WebPage in my UIWebView. I want to detect a button click on that page.

**code for that button in HTML file with Java Script is as follow:**

```
document.getElementById("fileUploadSection").innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block findJobsButton" id="txtUploadResume" onclick="validate();ok.performClick();"> </button>';
```

**Problem**: How can I detect the button is clicked & my native method is called?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: This answer provides an undocumented way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21648391/458205

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DJJavaInsertion](https://github.com/ddaddy/DJJavaInsertion) for a clever and easy way to let JavaScript run native methods.